# How can I determine if overflow occured using AND OR NOT and XOR?

Tags: overflow, bit, logical-operators

I'm trying to use only AND OR XOR and NOT to determine whether adding 2 binary number made of 4 bits will overflow.
I know, for example, that something like 1100 + 0100 will wind up as 1 | 0000. But how can I find this using just these logical operators?

I'm trying to get 1000 when overflow happens, and 0000 when it doesn't. This is easy enough since I can just use XOR with a mask to clear the last 3 bits.

Does anyone have suggestions for figuring this out?

Comment: This is entirely language dependant, what are you working with?

Comment: I'm trying to do this on paper for now. I suppose once I actually figure out how to do it, then I'll move up from there.

Comment: For now, I'm just trying to figure out (on paper), how to use the operators to detect overflow from adding any two binary numbers.

Comment: How could it be language dependant if it uses only logical operators... I'm thinking the question, John, will answer if I get it.

Comment: The best thing I could think of was something along the lines of using a mask of 1111 and XOR to make the 1st number negative, and then using XOR to add that to the 1st number and again to add it to the 2nd number, and then using AND to compare the result to the original 2nd number. If overflow happened, then the resulting bits would be different from the starting bits. (Unfortunately, this doesn't work, so I'm doing something wrong, but I don't see where).

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are ABCD and EFGH, ^ is AND, | is OR.

(A^E) | (B^F^(A|E)) | (C^G^(B|F)^(A|E)) | (D^H^(C|G)^(B|F)^(A|E))

I'm sure you can see the pattern there, so a recursive solution is pretty easy for numbers with more bits.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on the same question for the past few days and figured out the answer. Assuming there are two 4-bit numbers a, b and their sum stored in another 4-bit number s, there is an overflow when the first bits are following

```
a = 0, b = 0, s = 1
a = 1, b = 1, s = 0
```

(NOT a) AND (NOT b) AND s returns 1 for the first case of overflow
a AND b AND (NOT s) returns 1 for the second case. You can OR them for getting 1 as the first bit of the result. So,

```
((NOT a) AND (NOT b) AND s) OR (a AND b AND (NOT s))
```

expression returns 1xxx in case of overflow. ANDing the above expression with 1000 returns 1000 when there is an overflow and 0000 when there is no overflow. So, final answer is:

```
(((NOT a) AND (NOT b) AND s) OR (a AND b AND (NOT s))) AND 1000
```

PS: I assumed that the sum was available in another variable which the other answers didn't assume

Comment: Note: this answer uses `s = a+b` as an input. 
 The other answers don't, and this question is slightly different from [Procedure for finding if Overflow occurs on addition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62188572).  Having that sum as an input makes it much simpler, which is a good thing, and more relevant / interesting to real-world overflow situations.  (Arguably I shouldn't have closed that as a duplicate; I missed that difference originally.)  But anyway, good answer, I think that looks right.

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me know. I'll add the PS mentioning I assumed that the sum was available in another variable

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, using no loops or shifts. But its ugly:

```
if (
(a & 0x8) && (b & 0x8) || 
(((a & 0x8) || (b & 0x8)) && ((a & 0x4) && (b & 0x4))) ||
(((a & 0x8) || (b & 0x8)) && ((a & 0x4) || (b & 0x4)) && ((a & 0x2) && (b & 0x2))) ||
(((a & 0x8) || (b & 0x8)) && ((a & 0x4) || (b & 0x4)) && ((a & 0x2) || (b & 0x2)) && ((a & 0x1) && (b & 0x1)))
) {
  // overflow
}
```